# Web Scraping HTML Not same as Browser Result

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

For my project, I need google search results. I'm using python requests and BeautifulSoup. I get the results but they are not the same as the ones I see on my browser. I need the exact content that appears on my browser. I also tried urllib. But it also different from web results. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
import requests
import bs4

link = 'https://www.google.com/'
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }
response = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: What you mean _it is not same as browser result_ ?

Comment: Your browser generally store cookies, which may lead to inconsistent results, Try comparing the response with Incognito mode. Also a site like google personalizes your search results based upon your location

Comment: Yes. The result is not same as browser result. @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ

Answer (score 1):

Most websites run javascript to update the site. Some of them also attempt to detect crawlers.

Use a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) instead for crawling purposes.

As mentioned in the comments, some sites also use cookies. For example, google search results are so good primarily because they are customized for the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of JavaScript. To make it close to your results you see in your browser can pass additional [query `params` to your request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```py
params = {
  "q": "what is the best minecraft skin in 2021", # query 
  "gl": "uk",                                     # country to search from (United Kingdom)
  "hl": "en",                                     # language
  "google_domain": "google.com"                   # google domain
}
requests.get("YOUR_URL", params=params)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "what is the best minecraft skin in 2021",
  "gl": "uk",
  "hl": "en"
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

data = []

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  try: 
    snippet = result.select_one('#rso .lyLwlc').text
  except: snippet = None

  data.append({
      'title': title,
      'link': link,
      'snippet': snippet,
  })

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

-------
'''
[
  {
    "title": "The Ultimate Guide to Minecraft Skins in 2021 - CodaKid",
    "link": "https://codakid.com/minecraft-skins/",
    "snippet": null
  },
  {
    "title": "Search results for \"2021\" - Minecraft Skins",
    "link": "https://www.minecraftskins.com/search/skin/2021/1/",
    "snippet": "Red Dream Classic (4px arms) · Banan132. 1. 0. NewThealexx · NewThealexx. 1. 0. Zero Dragneel 2021 skin · reddwd123. 0. 0. contest // because i'm bored :(."
  },
  {
    "title": "Best Minecraft skins for 2021 | Rock Paper Shotgun",
    "link": "https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/best-minecraft-skins",
    "snippet": "12 Jul 2021 — Gamer Girl skin. This Gamer Girl Minecraft skin is one of the most popular skins out there. It's cute, it's well-designed, and with the grass ..."
  }
 # more ... 
]
'''
```

### Screenshot of what I was seeing in my browser (*same results*):

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that it can be done by default and you don't need to think about it and maintain the parser over time. All that needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want. Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "best minecraft skin in 2021",
    "hl": "en",
    "gl": "uk",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  # print(result['title'])
  # print(result['link'])
  print(f"Title: {result['title']}\nSummary: {result['snippet']}\nLink: {result['link']}\n")

-------
'''
Title: Search results for "2021" - Minecraft Skins
Summary: Red Dream Classic (4px arms) · Banan132. 1. 0. NewThealexx · NewThealexx. 1. 0. Zero Dragneel 2021 skin · reddwd123. 0. 0. contest // because i'm bored :(.
Link: https://www.minecraftskins.com/search/skin/2021/1/

Title: Best Minecraft skins for 2021 | Rock Paper Shotgun
Summary: Gamer Girl skin. This Gamer Girl Minecraft skin is one of the most popular skins out there. It's cute, it's well-designed, and with the grass ...
Link: https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/best-minecraft-skins

Title: 5 best Minecraft skins in 2021 - Sportskeeda
Summary: Five best Minecraft skins in 2021 · #5 Glowing Devil · #4 Glitching · #3 Rose and Bows · #2 Liquid Rainbow · #1 Save the bees.
Link: https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/5-best-minecraft-skins-2021

Title: Best Minecraft skins | PC Gamer
Summary: Cool skins; Girl skins; Anime Skins; Funny skins; Videogame skins; Skin sites. Best of Minecraft.
Link: https://www.pcgamer.com/uk/the-best-minecraft-skins/

# more ...
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.